# Angular 4 code to count number of clicks on a button

Tags: angular

I have a table where i want to count the number of clicks on a button. and the numbers are add the column.
I tried to search but i didn't get a code in angular 4

Comment: post your code and tell where you are stuck.

Comment: You can't ask a question without trying something even if you are a noob

Answer (score 7):

```
<button (click)="clickCount()">click</button>
```

{{count}} // print count any place

write a function int component

```
count: number = 0; declare before constructor


   clickCount(): void{
        this.count++
        }
```